# Why does it recognize as Unknown Column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to sort ordered by `updated_at` of `User` record, which is associated from `Code` table.

```
@codes = Code.joins(:user).where('body like ?', "%"+params[:search]+"%").order('user.updated_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

However, it won't let me sort:(

This is the error message I get.

**Error Message**

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'user.created_at' in 'order clause
```

Comment: have you tried `order(users.updated_at desc)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database table should be `users` not `user` (plural not singular).  Update your order method as follows:

```
order('users.updated_at DESC')
```